# Сравнение объектов в списке по их свойствам

Tags: c#, .net

Есть 2 списка `List<Cafe>` и `List<ManagmentCafe>`. `Cafe` и `ManagmentCafe` - собственные классы, которые содержат одно общее поле - Name. Необходимо провести сравнение этих двух списков по полю `Name` и удалить повторяющиеся из списка `List<Cafe>`.
Скажите, пожалуйста, это возможно? 
Через Foreach получить доступ к полям классов не получается...

Comment: Что значит "сравнение двух списков по полю Name и удалить повторяющиеся"? В List<Cafe> не должно быть элементов с Name, присутствуюем в List<ManagementCafe>? Или такие элементы могут быть, но не более одного? Неясно. В первом случае можно создать множество Name из List<ManagementCafe> и удалить из List<Cafe> те, чьё Name имеется в этом множестве. Во втором можно использовать Map

Comment: >получить доступ к полям классов не получается
почему?

Comment: откуда получить доступ? 
если вы скрыли их, поставив private, то понятно что вы к ним просто так не обратитесь.
Для foreach нужно этим классам наследоваться от интерфейса IEnumerable.

Comment: >> Для foreach нужно этим классам наследоваться от интерфейса IEnumerable.

Бред какой, кто вам это сказал?

Comment: @alexiz В List<Cafe> не должно быть элементов с Name, присутствующих в List<ManagementCafe>. Именно так.

Comment: Ну методу я уже предложил. Запихать все Name из List<ManagementCafe> во множестово (напр. HashSet<string>, если подойдёт для Name) и удалить элементы List<Cafe>, у которых Name содержится (Contains) в этом множестве.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё просто:

```
var managementNames = new HashSet<string>(ManagmentCafeList.Select(mc => mc.Name));
CafeList.RemoveAll(c => managementNames.Contains(c.Name));
```

Собственно, [[@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz) уже ответил.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Извиняюсь, может быть я жёстко туплю, но метод RemoveWhere() неприменим к CafeList, только к managementNames...

Comment: @Jembo_by: Ах да, [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx), конечно. Исправил.

Comment: @VladD Благодарю, то что нужно! Сократили мне 10 строк кода:)

Comment: @Jembo_by: не за что :)